# explain Format specifiers %f and gow does dot work in it

Tags: c

I know that Format specifiers in C are `%d` `%f` and for what purpose it is.
however, I recently learned that if I use `%.f` that output changes. how does dot here work?

dot in between of % and f changes result on console please explain it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float lenght,Width;

        printf("Enter Lenght :\n");
         scanf("%f",&lenght);
        printf("Enter Widht :\n");
         scanf("%f",&Width);

         printf("\nArea = %.f",lenght*Width);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of the `'.'` *precision specifier* is fully explained in [printf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: @Jens: This is not a duplicate; the purported original does not discuss the precision, particularly not with its decimal integer omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%d, %f are conversion specifier for printf and other function, this is not specific to the C language. Check [man printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (and [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) while you're at it).

With printf: if you use a period before the conversion specifier, you are asking for a precision. With the %f conversion, it affects the length of the fractional part.

From man printf:

> **The precision**
>
> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.') followed by an optional decimal digit string [...].  If the precision is given as just '.', or the precision is negative, the precision is taken to be zero. This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions, the number of digits to appear after the radix character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for g and G conversions, or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions.